# How to save/redirect output from Laravel Artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using `Artisan::call()` in one of my routes and would like to save the command output to a variable.

Is there any way to capture the STDOUT and STDERR generated by the artisan command?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a way:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

Route::get('/test', function()
{
    $output = new BufferedOutput;

    Artisan::call('list', array(), $output);

    return $output->fetch();
});
```

Comment: This works. However in my specific case, I ran into a problem. Could you take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113385/artisan-output-buffer-does-not-contain-all-output

Comment: This no longer works exactly, but if you use `Artisan::runCommand(`, it will work.

Answer (score 9):

When running a command from inside another command, here is how to get all the styling:

```
public function handle()
{
    Artisan::call('other:command', [], $this->getOutput());
}
```

Comment: Best answer! This shows the output in real time, instead of buffering it. Excellent for long running tasks.

Answer (score 7):

Seems the previous answers don't work in Laravel 5.2 any more (not sure about 5.1)
You can now use `Artisan::output();`

```
    $output = '';       
    if (!Schema::hasTable('migrations')) {
        Artisan::call('migrate:install', array());
        $output .= Artisan::output();
    }

    // Updates the migration, then seed the database
    Artisan::call('migrate:refresh', array('--force' => 1));
    $output .= Artisan::output();

    Artisan::call('db:seed', array('--force' => 1));
    $output .= Artisan::output();

    dd($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a unique solution that works well for me
In my base Command class which all my other commands extend I overloaded the output functions and then also If I need to I can overload them again in any extended commands... obviously writeLogFile is another custom function i made, however you can do whatever you want there

```
public function info($message,$verbosity = null)
{
    $this->writeLogFile($message);
    parent::info($message);
}
public function warn($message,$verbosity = null)
{
    $this->writeLogFile($message);
    parent::warn($message);
}
public function error($message,$verbosity = null)
{
    $this->writeLogFile($message);
    parent::error($message);
}
```