# Artisan output buffer does not contain all output

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the following code to redirect the output of an artisan command within a route.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

Route::get('/restart', function()
{
    $output = new BufferedOutput;
    Artisan::call('remote:restart', array(), $output);
    return $output->fetch();
});
```

This works for most cases. However if within the command I use the SSH component to run some tasks on a remote server, the output resulting from `SSH::into()->run()` will be disregarded by the above code.

If I run the artisan command manually, I get the following output:

```
start
[root@remote-host] (xxxx) Stopping php-fpm: 
[root@remote-host] (xxxx) [  OK  ]
[root@remote-host] (xxxx) Starting php-fpm: 
[root@remote-host] (xxxx) [  OK  ]
[root@remote-host] (xxxx) Stopping nginx: 
[root@remote-host] (xxxx) [  OK  ]
[root@remote-host] (xxxx) Starting nginx: 
[root@remote-host] (xxxx) [  OK  ]
end
```

But $output->fetch() only returns:

```
start end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the output interface on it:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

Route::get('/test', function()
{
    $output = new BufferedOutput;

    SSH::setOutput($output);

    SSH::run('ls -la');

    return $output->fetch();
});
```

Comment: Works! In my case, it's cleaner to pass a Closure to `SSH::run()` and call the display method on the connection object inside the closure.

Comment: @Dave would be cool if you can write that as an answer, thanks man.

Comment: @clusterBuddy Sorry I haven't touched Laravel for a long time now (original question was 7-8 years ago). I'm not sure what I wrote before is still relevant today.