# Laravel: Returning a value when running Artisan::call()

Tags: php, laravel

I have a long query to run in Laravel and in order to prevent a timeout from happening, I want to run it from the CLI. Am I correct to assume that using `Artisan::call()` can do this with a custom command? If this is correct, how do I return the data (serialized) taken from `Artisan::call()` back to the PHP file that called it?

I might be wrong about using Artisan to prevent timeouts on long scripts so please feel free to enlighten me. :)

Comment: I don't think using artisan will prevent timeouts. However to return the output from Artisan::call see this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20111569/942846