# Getting console output in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to capture the output of a console command to be sent by email as well when requested. How can I do this?

How do I get the output generated from the following `$this->info()` calls?

```
$r = processData();

$this->info("\nSubmitted data:");
$this->info("SubmissionId: " . $r['submission_id']);
$this->info("Status: " . $r['status']);
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20111569/1903366) help?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Unfortunately it doesn't because I need to capture a specific segment of the console output from with the executing command itself. The solution is for calling the command externally and capturing the output. Not sure how I would adapt it (I did try).

Comment: Okay. You could override the `info` method in your command (or a new command base class if you need it often) and then save it in there. Would that be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just replace the `$this->info()` calls with a simple echo command and output buffer control. Looks good enough in the console and catches the data requested for emailing.

Example:

```
$r = processData();

if ($this->option('email-results'))
    ob_start();

echo "\nSubmitted data:";
echo "\nSubmissionId: " . $r['submission_id'];
echo "\nStatus: " . $r['status'];

if ($this->option('email-results')) {
    mail(
        $this->option('email-results'),
        'Results on ' . $start_time->toDateTimeString(),
        ob_get_contents()
    );

    ob_end_flush();
}
```

Comment: I solved it with just overriding the info method and keeping track of a local protected buffer but still calling `parent::info()` for the console logging. `$this->buffer .= $data . "\n";parent::info($data);`

Answer (score 0):

an Artisan method could help:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::output()
```