# Laravel console: How to output variables using

Tags: laravel

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936315/getting-console-output-in-laravel) but the solution therein doesn't use the Laravel method.

I wanna do something like this:

```
$this->info('This is the result: ', $result);
```

Comment: You could make your own `$this->infoAndLog` function in your class that calls `$this->info()` *and* does something else. (Or extend the `info()` function.)

Comment: What about `$this->info('This is the result: ' .  print_r($result, true));` ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for:

```
$output = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput(2);

$output->writeln('This is the result: ', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->info('This is the result: ');
dump($result);
```

You can use `dump()` for print print objects

Answer (score 0):

Btw, Do you know you can include variable inside double quote to output, the first basic thing of php. 
`$this->info("This is the result: {$result}")`