# How to save/redirect output from Laravel 5 Artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have tried the method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111287/how-to-save-redirect-output-from-laravel-artisan-command) but this doesn't work on my Laravel 5 installation.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

Route::get('/test', function()
{
    $output = new BufferedOutput;

    Artisan::call('testCommand', array(), $output);

    return $output->fetch();
});
```

My command;

```
public function fire()
{
    $this->info('No output visible');
}
```

Any suggestions what I might do wrong? Or is it something that has changed in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get this to work using `Artisan::output()`, which returns the output of the latest command.

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{    
    Artisan::call('testCommand', array());

    return Artisan::output();
});
```

should do it for you.

Answer (score 6):

I did this

```
php artisan your:command >> output.txt
```

worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working off the command line then you can pipe through the `tee` command to write to a file and `stdout` at the same time.

```
php artisan <command> | tee <filename>
```

Comment: not working now

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, replacing BufferedOutput with oldschool PHP made it work for me, perhaps it works for you too:

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    ob_start();
    Artisan::call('testCommand');
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
});
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I am using the command shell and PHPUnit and the $output is always empty.