# Create log file while running artisan command directly in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this Command in the `Kernel` class :

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('products:import')
        ->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/import.log'));
}
```

The method creates a file named `import.log` that contains the logging that I added while importing the products, and it works fine. But I need to be able to just run `php artisan products:import` directly and get the file created too without calling the `schedule` method in the `Kernel` class, or using `php artisan schedule:run`.

I didn't find in the docs either. What should I add to `php artisan products:import` to get the file created?.

EDIT : if I run `php artisan schedule:run`, the log file gets created because of the `appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/import.log'));`, but if I run `php artisan products:import` directly, the log file isn't created. I need to know what should I add to the `php artisan products:import` command line to make it work in this case too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662577/how-to-save-redirect-output-from-laravel-5-artisan-command

Comment: `php artisan products:import >> import.log` did the trick, thanks.

Comment: Add that as an answer so that people know it's been resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save/redirect output from Laravel 5 Artisan command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662577/how-to-save-redirect-output-from-laravel-5-artisan-command)

Answer (score 0):

Override [`run` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v7.17.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php#L114) for your command and configure the `$output` stream to use a `StreamOutput` instead of a `ConsoleOutput`.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ImportCommand extends Command 
{ 
    function run(InputInterface $input=null, OutputInterface $output=null) {
        $output = new StreamOutput(fopen(storage_path('logs/import.log'), 'a', false));
        parent::run($input, $output);
    }
    
    function handle() {
         echo "Do stuff";
    }
}
```