# How to echo a string into a view in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 4.2 framework (will be upgraded soon) and am calling an `artisan` command from a controller with a return redirect back.

My issue is when I call the command, the command `echo` some stuff for me (which is helpful when I call it from the terminal) but now since am using it in a method, I want the same `echos` showing in my view as flash message.

I will write the following example just to clarify my issue.

**My Command:**

```
public function fire()
{ 
    // Do stuff.
    echo $vars 
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
function foo() {

      // Some input here

      Artisan::call('command');


      return Redirect::back(); // <-- want to add the echos of the command. 
}
```

So I want to show the `$var` in my views, am not sure if it's possible if not am open to other suggestions that can give me the same concept (keep in mind if am replacing the `echo` with something else it got to show in both view and terminal when I run the command).

Note: I tried Ajax but my issue was with me sending a file as param, tried the FormData Object but it didn't work with me.

Comment: This sounds like it calls for [output buffering](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). You can leave the `artisan` command as it is, and then wrap your `Artisan::call()` call with start and end commands, to grab the output and put it into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing my command little bit.

**Command:**

```
function fire()
{
  // replaced the echo with the following.
  $this->info('what ever you want ur message you want to put in console');

 }
```

**Controller**

```
function foo()
{

  $output =  new BufferedOutput();

  Artisan::call('command', [arguments], $output);

  return Redirect::back()->with('flash_message', $output->fetch());
}
```

Guess the buffered output works with command outputs which can be found in [Laravel Documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#building-a-command) not `echo's`

Answer (score 2):

Storing data in the session is a good way of keeping persistent data throughout multiple requests.  Session flashing is a way to keep data just for the next request, which is perfect for redirects.  Laravel uses this internally for old input data when there is a validation error.

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#flash-data

```
Session::flash('key', 'value');
```

This will only be kept for the next request, in which you'd be able to use `Session::get('key')` to retrieve it.

Comment: Just to make sure that i got you here, I can do Session::flash('vars', $vars); 
 then showing it in the blade ?!

Comment: Yes, then you'd retrieve it with `Session::get('vars')` later.

Comment: If this doesn't work, it may not if Artisan doesn't respect sessions, I'd consider looking to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111287/how-to-save-redirect-output-from-laravel-artisan-command

Comment: i tried the output and it didn't work with me. Let me check the session flash!