# How to get Artisan::call('command:name') output in a variable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

Is it possible to get $output as follows:

```
$output = Artisan::call('command:name');
```

I have tried many solutions in different posts but it didn't work on my Laravel 5.2.

Comment: You should really think about updating your laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111287/how-to-save-redirect-output-from-laravel-artisan-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save/redirect output from Laravel Artisan command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111287/how-to-save-redirect-output-from-laravel-artisan-command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the `output` method on Artisan

```
Artisan::call('command:name');
$output = Artisan::output();
```

Make sure you are using one of the available output methods like `$this->line('output');` in the actual Artisan command. More info in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/artisan#writing-output).

Comment: The issue is in 1st line that automatically echoes the output, so 2nd line is of no use.

Comment: How do you generate this output in the command itself? You should do something like `$this->line('my output');`

Comment: Ooo ... Let me try it ... Thanks for pointed this out @Bram Verstraten

Comment: $this->line worked. I then used Artisan::output(). Thanks for saving me ! @Bram

Comment: No worries. Make sure to mark this as the accepted answer so other people with the same problem can find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but as your are using such old version of Laravel maybe the best for your case is one that will not require a rewrite when you finally migrate to a newer version. Have you tried perhaps the vanilla PHP methods `system`, `shell_exec` and `passthru`?

- [`system`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) will return just the last line of the command on succes and FALSE on failure
- [`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) will return the entire output but without a way to fetch the output status code
- [`passthru`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) will not return any output instead it will output all on `stdout`. Although it can be put into a variable using output cache methods (i.e. `ob_start` and `ob_get_contents`)

In any case you should call those methods using as argument the CLI version of the command you wish to run:

```php
$output = shell_exec("php artisan command:here");
```

P.S. If you by any chance have a user input that you want to pass as parameter to a artisan command, make sure you escape it with `escapeshellcmd` first.